# new window and table from javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take information that a user entered in a form, and transfer that to a table on a different window.

```
function submit() {
    window.open('Table Page.html');
    document.write('<table border = "1" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "5">')

    for (i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
        document.write('<tr>')
        document.write('<td>row ' + i + ',column 0</td>')
    }
}
```

however, it doesn't appear on the new window, but rather in the original window. How do I make it take information from input fields, like password fields and name fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open window with dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924012/open-window-with-dynamic-content)

Comment: why you are using new window? try dialog

Comment: mainly because thats what my homework says to do

Comment: If you only need to worry about modern browsers and the page is static after first generation, you may want to consider making a _Blob_ or _data URI_ describing the file instead of a `document.write`. This will also mean you never need to _REQUEST_ for `Table Page.html`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do in in the context of the window you opened. In this case, you open a new window but afterwards use `document.write` still in the first window. You could do it something like this:

```
var NewWindow = window.open('Table Page.html');
NewWindow.document.write('....');
```

Comment: ok, yeah that works, i didnt understand why it didnt before, but thank you very much.

Comment: @NatJohns It didn't before because `document` and `NewWindow.document` point to different instances of _Document_; each within it's own _Window_.